# xpages - Checkbox null

Tags: checkbox, null, xpages

I was pointed to this site for my issue below.

I have borrowed the checkbox code from OpenNTF.org.  The project is - http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=CDD107F4006F7D5C8625775F001B8C61

I have integrated it into a xPage and it works fine when run in the notes client on local, in the web browser and on handheld devices.  But when run on a replica on a domino server, the value for the number of columns comes into the is null.  The domino server is 8.5.3 FP1.

Not sure why is only errors when on the domino server via the notes client when it works just fine in the  client locally.

Thanks,
Walt

Here is the error

Unexpected runtime error
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
Error source
Page Name:/Company.xsp
Control Id: rowRepeat

Exception
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=37: 'compositeData.FieldValues' is
null

JavaScript code

```
Math.ceil(compositeData.FieldValues.length / compositeData.numberOfColumns);
```

Stack Trace

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.getValue(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.createDataModel(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.getDataModel(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeRows(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule $AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule $ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService (Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

.

```
com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=1, col=37: compositeData.FieldValues' is null
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.binaryop.ASTBinaryDefaultOp.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTArgumentList.interpretArguments(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.getValue(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.createDataModel(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.getDataModel(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeRows(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule $AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule
$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService (Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should write this on the Discussion for the component on OpenNTF. As it may be an application issue. The developer of that component would be the best to answer it.

Comment: Do you have enough rights in the ACL and the same data on the server replica?

Comment: I have emailed the developers of the project, they suggested I post it on here.  There ACL is good, since I am accessing it with the same ID via the browser as well as the notes client.  If it was and ID issue, the browser or handheld should show the same results.

Comment: It works for the handheld from the server and does not work for PC browser from the same server replica?

Comment: I'd still poke the developer some more. ;)  compositeData object is not initialised. Is that something you created or the component. The other option is to reduce it to a sample and paste the source in your question.

Comment: The application works for handheld devices, accessing the server, web browsers accessing the server, Notes clients working on local.  But when a notes client accesses the application on the server(Same server as the web browser) it errors out.

I will try to reduce and post while I am at Lotusphere.

Comment: My guess is that it just has not been tested in XPiNC and does not work in that setup.

Comment: Edit your question a specify value you set to FieldValues property of custom control. It seems it uses some lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script interpreter error is "'compositeData.FieldValues' is null". As is true in the context of any Custom Control, `compositeData` is the variable that refers to the map of properties passed into the Custom Control. Hence, if `compositeData.FieldValues` is `null`, then whatever expression is assigned to the `FieldValues` property of the Custom Control, that expression is evaluating to `null`.

In your case, the expression `compositeData.FieldValues.length` throws an error, because `null` does not have a length (...or any other properties or methods, for that matter).

You've indicated that this works fine in the following scenarios:

- Notes client, local replica
- Browser accessing server
- Mobile device accessing server

What all three scenarios have in common is that the code is running on local. When you access an XPage via the browser (including mobile), you're accessing some server, but the code that executes is local to itself... it doesn't have to make an NRPC call to another Domino server to run the code.

So the one scenario where it's failing is the one scenario where that's not true: accessing a server replica from the Notes client. I'm guessing that the expression you're passing to `FieldValues` is using `@DbLookup()` or a similar operation but not properly accounting for what server the code is running on, causing it to pass `null` to the Custom Control.

Comment: It does do a lookup, I will check out the dblookup formula

Comment: That was it, was not looking at the server in the lookup.  Was looking for a local DB.  Thanks for the help